# Regex find specific string between two other strings

Tags: html, regex

I have a .html with obfuscated class names, something like this class="cd hk aw hs vu me hr". I want to replace only one specific classnames(for example "hk") in the entire html.I need a regex expression that can help me achieve that.

I have found this expression:
`(?<=class="[^"]*).*(?=")`

So I tried the following:
`(?<=class="[^"]*)(.*hk.*)(?=")`
but it returns also all the classes within the same body.[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLVeO.png)

It should return the hk word alone

Any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mandatory Surgeon General warning: [you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1428679).

In this very limited case, you *might* use

```
(<[^>]*class\s*=\s*"[^"]*)\bhk\b([^"]*")
```

and replace it with `\1whatever\2`. Then "hk" becomes "whatever" provided it's inside a class inside a HTML tag. The \b specifier will prevent "ohka" from matching and the \s ensures that "class = " and "class=" will be treated the same. You will need a multiline modifier for the case of

```
<p class
     ="ab hk cd" style="display: block">
```

You can experiment using https://regex101.com .

## Update (clarification):

```
(<[^>]*class\s*=\s*"[^"]*)\bhk\b([^"]*")
```

*will*, indeed, find `<body class="ab hk cd" style="x">` and match **and replace** the sequence `<body class="ab hk cd"`. Note, in the regex, that the first part - the one before "hk" - is parenthesized, and so is the part after.

The "trick" is in the replacement formula, where I specified "\1whatever\2" (in some libraries it could be $1whatever$2, or ${1}whatever${2}, or {$1}whatever{$2} and so on). The meaning is that *the content of the first parenthesized group goes into \1*, and so on.

So the three groups will be:

```
'<body class="ab '      captured by '(<[^>]*class\s*=\s*"[^"]*)' into $1
'hk'                    captured by "\bhk\b" and discarded
 cd"                    captured by '([^"]*")' into $2
```

and the replacement `\1whatever\2` will become

```
 \1                  whatever   \2
 '<body class="ab '  whatever   'cd"'
```

which is the desired output. The replacement of the first and third groups with themselves feels needless and wasteful, but I know no other means of doing this - regex replacement requires regenerating the *whole* match, and the "extra" parts are required to correctly frame the match itself.

(You could use this kind of syntax to swap two strings around a pivot, for example).

Comment: If I add the suggested Regex in VS Code it will replace the entire <body class="cd hk aw hs vu me hr"> instead of only hk class.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Edit: I searched more on google and I found the answer with groupping in VsCode.Thank you very much!